# Why applying height makes scrollbar appear on wrong breakpoint?

Tags: css

I have a problem with scrollbar appearing at wrong pixel point on my website. I narrowed problem to simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/LoZrwo) structure.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.cont__inner {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .cont__inner {
    width: 950px;
  }
}

.cont__inner_main {
  padding: 0 45px;
}

.why {
  height: 115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cont__inner cont__inner_main ">
    <div class="why">adssd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem comes when i apply height `700px` to `div.why`. 
You can see that width of container is `1100px + 45px padding` on both sides , so its `1190px` total

I've set media screen breakpoint lower just to track when scrollbar appears. 
You can test yourself, it comes up at `1206px` and no element overlap document width at that moment. Removing `heigth 700px` solves problem, but what did it even influence width ?

Comment: You can add `* { box-sizing: border-box}`

Comment: i know about this prop, but i dont need it here. i want separate width for content and paddings

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **width: auto** in &_main

```
&_main 
  padding: 0 $mn * 3
  width: auto
```

Comment: it works, but why is it adding scrollbar. i wanna know mechanics please

Comment: wait. i need a fixed width here

Comment: heigth: 115px -> when your screen width is between 1170 and 1190 you have 1100+45+45 width block content, it means that (1170; 1190) < 1190 const width block, so you have horiz. scrollbar.  The width does not include the thickness of the borders around the element, the value of indents and margins

Comment: u saying obvious things bro. i know when scrollbar appears. but why is it appears 1191 - 1206 px ? can u say to me ? and it depends on heigth somehow, i mean if i remove it scrollbar dissapears